# New to C++ and I get compiler error when using template function

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors, g++

I'm quite new to C++ programming and it seams that I have fundamental problems in understanding how the compiling and linking works. Here is my Minimum example:
I have thre files a.hpp, a.cpp and b.cpp.

a.hpp:

```
namespace A {
   template<typename T>
   double helpA(T t1,T t2);
}
```

a.cpp:

```
#include "a.hpp"
namespace A {
   template<typename T>
   double helpA(T t1, T t2){
      return(t1 +t2);
   }
}
```

b.cpp (main)

```
#include <iostream>
#include "a.hpp"


int main (int argc, char *argv[]){

        double t = A::helpA(1.0,2.3);
        std::cout << t << "\n";

}
```

When I now try to compile the Thing by calling

```
g++ b.cpp a.cpp
```

I get the following error:

```
b.cpp:(.text+0x24): undefined reference to `double A::helpA<double>(double, double)' 
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Every help is appriciated